# I want to replace dplyr style, but I don't know how to do it in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to replace this code into dplyr style.

```
financials[is.na(ForecastEarningsPerShare), ForecastEarningsPerShare := ForecastEarningsPerShare2]
```

Could you tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 5):

From `data.table`:

```r
financials[is.na(ForecastEarningsPerShare),
            ForecastEarningsPerShare := ForecastEarningsPerShare2]
```

Into `dplyr`, perhaps literally:

```r
financials %>%
  mutate(
    ForecastEarningsPerShare = if_else(is.na(ForecastEarningsPerShare),
                                       ForecastEarningsPerShare2,
                                       ForecastEarningsPerShare)
  )
```

But a slightly easier-to-read method:

```r
financials %>%
  mutate(
    ForecastEarningsPerShare = coalesce(ForecastEarningsPerShare,
                                        ForecastEarningsPerShare2)
  )
```

where `coalesce` uses the first non-`NA` value in the arguments and returns it (vectorized).

Comment: Thanks!!!  It was very easy to understand.